# Rx argumentException with webclient

Tags: system.reactive, windows-phone-7.1

I am working with the Reactive Extensions, to easy download webpages with the WebClient on Windows Phone.
When I run the following code, I get an ArgumentExceptoin on the  Subscribe call.

Parameter name: {0}

Parameter name: type

```
public IObservable<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs> StartRequest(string uri)
    {

        var _browser = new WebClient();
        var obs = Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler,
            DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(

                h => _browser.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
                h => _browser.DownloadStringCompleted -= h)
            .Where(e => !e.Cancelled)
            .Retry(3)
            .SelectMany(
                e => (e.Error == null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(e.Result))
                         ? Observable.Return(e)
                         : Observable.Throw<DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(e.Error))
            .Take(1);



        _browser.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));

        return obs;
    }

 var obs = StartRequest("http://www.google.com");

        obs.Subscribe(
            x => Console.WriteLine(x.Result)

            );
```

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that you're using the `FromEvent` extension rather than the `FromEventPattern` extension.

The former is for non-standard events and the latter for those that follow the "sender/eventargs" pattern.

That said, you still have a few more issues with your observable.

- The instance of `WebClient` is never disposed of. You should make
  sure that happens, but because you're using an observable you need to
  use the `Using` extension method.
- Putting a `Where` before the `Take(1)` may mean that your observable
  will never end.
- The `Retry` is also not going to do the right thing for you. If the
  "DownloadStringCompleted" observable has an error then retrying it
  will re-attach to the event, but the event will never return a new
  value because you're not calling `DownloadStringAsync` again.

What you want to do with this kind of observable is make it re-execute the web call every time a new observer subscribes, but, when a subscription is shared (if the observable is published, for example) then you don't want the web call to re-execute. You kind of want to have your cake and eat it too.

Here's how to do it:

```
public IObservable<string> CreateDownloadStringObservable(string uri)
{
    return Observable.Create<string>(o =>
    {
        var result = new ReplaySubject<string>();
        var inner = Observable.Using(() => new WebClient(), wc =>
        {
            var obs = Observable
                .FromEventPattern<
                    DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler,
                    DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
                        h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
                        h => wc.DownloadStringCompleted -= h)
                .Take(1);
            wc.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
            return obs;
        }).Subscribe(ep =>
        {
            if (ep.EventArgs.Cancelled)
            {
                result.OnCompleted();
            }
            else
            {
                if (ep.EventArgs.Error != null)
                {
                    result.OnError(ep.EventArgs.Error);
                }
                else
                {
                    result.OnNext(ep.EventArgs.Result);
                    result.OnCompleted();
                }
            }
        }, ex =>
        {
            result.OnError(ex);
        });
        return new CompositeDisposable(inner, result.Subscribe(o));
    });
}
```

Now you can call it like this:

```
IObservable<string> obs =
    CreateDownloadStringObservable("http://www.google.com")
        .Retry(3);
```

Notice that the `Retry` is now outside of the request method where it should belong (unless you add a `retry` argument to the method call).

Answer (score 1):

You can't use Retry with FromEvent, because FromEvent is a *hot* observable - you'll just get the same result 3 times. The easiest way to fix your existing code is via Observable.Defer:

```
string uri = "http://www.whatever.com";

var webClient = Observable.Defer(() => {
    var browser = new WebClient();
    var ret =  Observable.FromEvent<DownloadStringCompletedEventHandler, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs>(
        h => _browser.DownloadStringCompleted += h,
        h => _browser.DownloadStringCompleted -= h);

    browser.DownloadStringAsync(new Uri(uri));
    return ret;
});

webClient
    .Timeout(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15))
    .Retry(3);
```

Defer means that instead of WebClient being created immediately, it will be created for everyone who Subscribe()'s to the Observable, which is what is required for Retry.